# Problem with Invoking Octave commands from c#

Tags: c#, octave

I am trying to use surf function of Octave to plot 3d data from my c# application.

I use Process.Start() to start Octave and Process.WriteLine() to send commands 
The same method works fine to plot using gnuplot but it's not working with Octave

```
Process octavePro;
        StreamWriter octaveStWr;
        string octavepath = @"C:\Octave\Octave-5.1.0.0\mingw64\bin\octave-cli-5.1.0.exe";
```

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        octavePro = new Process();
        octavePro.StartInfo.FileName = octavepath;
        octavePro.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        octavePro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        octavePro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        octavePro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        octavePro.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        octavePro.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(InterProcOutputHandler);
        octavePro.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(InterProcOutputHandler);
```

```
            octavePro.Start();
            octaveStWr = octavePro.StandardInput;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            octaveStWr.WriteLine("info");
            octaveStWr.WriteLine("surf([1 2 3; 2 3 4; 3 4 5])");
            octaveStWr.Flush();
        }
```

When I execute the two command "info" and "surf([1 2 3; 2 3 4; 3 4 5])" in Octave-CLI, I get application information and 3d plot for the data respectively.
But when I try to execute it from C# application, only a terminal window is started and nothing is displayed in the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to increase the sleep time for the initialization of Octave. Depending on the duration of each command you may need add more sleeps. Also use [`waitfor`](https://octave.org/doc/v5.1.0/GUI-Utility-Functions.html#XREFwaitfor) to suspend the execution of Octave until the figure is closed.

```
octavePro.Start();
octaveStWr = octavePro.StandardInput;
octavePro.BeginOutputReadLine();
octavePro.BeginErrorReadLine(); 
Thread.Sleep(5000);
octaveStWr.WriteLine("info");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
octaveStWr.WriteLine("waitfor(surf([1 2 3; 2 3 4; 3 4 5]))");
```

Comment: thanks for informative answer
"waitfor" solved the problem.
but what if I need to update the plotting in realtime without closing the figure?

Comment: with timeout property of "waitfor" function, the min timeout is 1 sec. which limits the refresh rate.
Is there any work around to improve the refresh rate?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. You can use `uiwait`. Consider the following example : `octaveStWr.WriteLine("for i=1:10;imshow(rand(100),[]);drawnow;end;");octaveStWr.WriteLine("uiwait()");`